# Circle within a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to build a statistical model that would detect the likelyhood of an interaction with a rod within a cone of variance.

I have managed to create the circle within a matrix, but I want to differentiate the inside, from the outside of the circle. Is there a method by which I could make everything outside of the circle function a separate value?

Here is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def my_unit_circle(r):  
   d = 2*r + 1  
   rx, ry = d/2, d/2  
   x, y = np.indices((d, d))  
   return (np.abs(np.hypot(rx - x, ry - y)-r) < 0.5).astype(int)

model = my_unit_circle(300)

model[300:325,0:600] = 2

plt.matshow(model)  
plt.show()'''
```

Which gives me this:

[image: Matshow image]

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.where` can be used to create an array with values depending on a condition:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def my_unit_circle(r):
   d = 2*r + 1
   rx, ry = d/2, d/2
   x, y = np.indices((d, d))
   return np.where(np.hypot(rx - x, ry - y) < r,  1, 0)

model = my_unit_circle(300)

model[300:325,0:600] = 2

plt.matshow(model)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]